# How to pass variables as expressions in Bigquery timestamp_diff

Tags: google-bigquery

Currently, I am trying to check the timestamp difference in hours with expressions passed as a variables through the command line. But I am unable to get the desired output when passing through variables.

```
a=2019-11-1812:49:43
b=2020-04-04 20:32:33

timediff=$(bq query --nouse_legacy_sql \ 'SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP "'$a'", TIMESTAMP "$b", HOUR);')
```

Looks like the variables I am passing are not recognized. Can someone help me understand the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Hemant's answer to further contribute with the community I will provide an alternative method.

As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#using_timestamps_in_parameterized_queries), it is possible to use parameterized queries in BigQuery using the Command-Line interface (CLI). You need to use the flag `--parameter` within your *bq query* command in order to specify the varibles/parameters you will use.

This flag must be in the format `name:type:value`. Although, if type is omitted it will used as *STRING*. As an example:

```
timediff= $(bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 
--parameter='ts_value:TIMESTAMP:2016-12-07 08:00:00' 
--parameter='ts_value1:TIMESTAMP:2016-12-07 09:00:00' 
'SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(@ts_value,@ts_value1, HOUR)')

echo $timediff
```

And the output is:

```
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|  -1 |
+-----+
```

You could use `--format=csv` to format the output as a line:

```
f0_ -1
```

In addition, I would like to add that you can use aliases to simplify your query. For instance:

```
alias bq_set="bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --format=pretty"

timediff=$(bq_set 
--parameter='ts_value:TIMESTAMP:2016-12-07 08:00:00' 
--parameter='ts_value1:TIMESTAMP:2016-12-07 09:00:00' 
'SELECT
   TIMESTAMP_DIFF(@ts_value,@ts_value1, HOUR)')

echo $timediff
```

The output:

```
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|  -1 |
+-----+
```

As you can see it was just an alternative to simply your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes around the variables, but double-quotes around the entire query. For example:

```
a='2019-11-18 12:49:43'
b='2020-04-04 20:32:33'

timediff=$(bq query --format=csv --nouse_legacy_sql "SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP '$a', TIMESTAMP '$b', HOUR);" | awk 
'NR>1')

echo $timediff
-3319
```

Comment: Thank you. I applied the same